# Is it possible to send document for signature without recipient info in the envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

Our application needs a generic pdf to be signed by the user, the user can be anyone, whoever opts on sign, we are not capturing user name/email etc. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not it is not possible, for legal reasons, there has to be a name and email that identify the person who signs. 
There are ways for the end-user to provide it, if you don't know that ahead of time. One way is to use the PowerForm feature where a URL is used for end-users to start the signing process and only then provide their name and email.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

1. As Inbar suggests, use a DocuSign Powerform. The signer is first asked for their name. Then they see the signing ceremony.
2. If a simple "acknowledge" style of signature is needed, use DocuSign Click.